# what is the input for this get latest price function call

Tags: solidity, ether, chainlink

[image: confused on input after call is made]

after deploying this contract on rinkeby it uses a bit of gas to get onto the network, when i use the call function the gas denomination leaves and there is another input that is not clear to me it is the    **0x8e1...5f473**

Comment: Please, the next time include the code as text. Also you could paste the whole input.

Answer (score 0):

There is no input needed besides the aggregator contract address. Which in your screenshot is pointed at ETHUSD.
The answer is even displayed in your screenshot "170008744161" = 1700.087usd

Answer (score 0):

The first 4 bytes of the input are the function id [0x8e15f473](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=8e15f473).

Searching in the [Ethereum Signature Database](https://www.4byte.directory/) it correspond to

```
getLatestPrice()
```

Which makes sense because that's the function you are calling.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to the value of the `input` field in the output showing in your remix console here.

The input is the hash of the function - this is how the bytecode of your function looks (after encoding to hexadecimal).

In addition to Ismael's answer, you should keep in mind that when you compile your contract the whole things gets converted to bytecode to deploy on chain.

The function signature `getLatestPrice()`, when hashed, looks like `8e15f473`.

You can check this yourself in Remix.

Go to the "compiler" button on the left panel.  Then make sure you choose the right contract from the `CONTRACT` dropdown.  Hit the Compile button.

Then down the bottom of that panel click the button `Compilation Details`.

You'll see a window pop up that has your contract name on top (make sure its the right contract!).

scroll down and you'll see something called `Function Hashes`. Expand that
and you'll see an object with that same hash in it, and it tells you which function it maps to.

[image]